# {"error": "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"msf:117971\""} in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using the FilePickerManager library in react native, but it doesn't work for all phones, in some when uploading the file it prints the error {"error": "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "msf:117971\ ""}

this is the function in charge of uploading the file:

```
const loadFile = async (type) => {

    FilePickerManager.showFilePicker(null, (response) => {
        console.log('Response = ', response);

        if (response.didCancel || response.error) {
            setText('Archivo no cargado');
            setShow(true);
            return;
        }

        file = {
            name: response.fileName,
            type: response.type,
            uri: response.uri
        };

        if (file != undefined) {
            if (type == 'cam_com') {
                console.log('cam_com')
                setFileCommerce(file);
                setText('Archivo de Camara de Comercio cargado');
                setShow(true);
            }
            if (type == 'rut') {
                console.log('rut')
                setFileRut(file);
                setText('Archivo RUT cargado');
                setShow(true);
            }
        }

        console.log('file', file)
    });

}
```

Comment: `msf:117971` is not a number is the message.

Comment: Did you find any solution?